# Is there an easy way to add a button to the action bar for a child activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to add buttons to the action bar in an android studio app to a child activity, but I only manage to add it to the main activity. Does anybody know how I can do this?

I would like the "OK"-button to be where I have drawn it in orange.

Main Activity with action bar.
[image: main activity with action bar]

child activity with action bar
[image: child activity with action bar]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Action bar. You can use only a view that background color is you want. After You set your button above your colored area.

İn Android Studio :

Values>Styles

Use this :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

instead of

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Back to your layout:

```
// Change your background with LinearLayout's background propoerty
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"

       android:background="#FFA908"


       >


       // You can put here whatever you want. İf you wish image or button.



       <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Example"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
           />

       <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Example"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           />



   </LinearLayout>
```

İf you can use like this. You don't need to use Action Bar. And You can create whatever you want easily.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a menu for your activity:

Inside **res**->**menu** select **new**->**Menu resource file**
[image: New Menu resource file]

In your new menu xml file write the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_action_ok"
        android:title="Ok"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Basically you're creating a menu with an option named 'Ok', but you can have more options if you need.
You can also customize the view of this option if you want with:

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/filter_ka"
```

In your parent activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test, menu);
    return true;
}
```

R.menu.**menu_test** is the name of your menu file.

Finally to receive the click of your menu options, you should override the following function:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.menu_action_ok) {
        //Your code
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Now you should have a menu like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a menu for this one. Suppose you create `add_menu`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:title="ADD"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

After creating the menu, inflate it to your child activity by using the following.

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```